# Nested resources with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is my routes file.

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts'

resources :users do
  resources :articles
end
```

How can i show all articles of 
the users on the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  (HAML):

```
- current_user.articles.each do |article|
  = article.name
```

You have to be sure that you have built an association between users and articles correctly in your `articles_controller`.